React Router + vite + Dynamic Routes
I am having the rough time with React router dom with vite with dynamic route paths. I want to be able to use the following routes:
'http://localhost:8000' // nothing. ignore
'http://localhost:8000/tenant' // dynamic tenant detail page
'http://localhost:8000/tenant/subscription' // dynamic subscription detail page
'http://localhost:8000/tenant/subscription/manage' // static subscription manage page

When I run the app in dev mode everything works. When I run vite preview I get the tenant page to load but I never get the subscription page to load. Nor do the static pages after. See set up below. Any ideas?
// main.tsx
// BrowserRouter is here b/c this app is a micro frontend, fyi
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter >
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

// App.tsx
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Routes>
        <Route path=":tenant" element={<TenantPage />} />
        <Route path=":tenant/:subscription" element={< SubscriptionPage />} />
        <Route path=":tenant/:subscription/manage" element={< ManageSubscriptionPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


What all does vite preview do? The basic gist is that whatever/however you are hosting and serving the app it should be configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app. Can you [edit] to clarify when not running a local development server what exactly you are doing or what exactly is setup/configured?

There doesn't seem anything wrong with vite preview at all. Tried running with npm run preview and it works all good.

I found the issue. In our vite.config.ts file we had base: '' instead of base: '/' which is the default value.
